# Pre-whitening longitudinal MLM

Tags: multilevel-analysis, longitudinal-data-analysis, whitening

I am conducting longitudinal multilevel models (Level-1 = Daily observations; Level-2 = PARTICIPANT). Predictors and outcome variables are measured every day.

Do I need to pre-whiten my data (and why)?

Comment: What is the research question you are trying to answer with your model? Also, can you provide more details about the initial specification of your model?

Comment: Research questions: Do daily changes in motivation for physical activity lead to changes in daily steps?

Comment: i.e. Do individuals take more steps on the days they report high motivation to be active